# sudo apt-get -f install error gcc-6-base

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies

I can not install anyhing new in my comp allways getting this error even if I try sudo apt-get -f install. Using Ubuntu 17.04 64 bits

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgcc1:i386:
 libgcc1:i386 depends on gcc-6-base (= 6.3.0-12ubuntu2); however:
  Package gcc-6-base:i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libgcc1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc6:i386:
 libc6:i386 depends on libgcc1; however:
  Package libgcc1:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libc6:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpcre3:i386:
 libpcre3:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpcre3:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgpg-error0:i386:
 libgpg-error0:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.15); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgpg-error0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libselinux1:i386:
 libselinux1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.8); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.
 libselinux1:i386 depends on libpcre3; however:
  Package libpcre3:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libselinux1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of liblzma5:i386:
 liblzma5:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.17); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package liblzma5:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of liblz4-1:i386:
 liblz4-1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package liblz4-1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgcrypt20:i386:
 libgcrypt20:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.15); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.
 libgcrypt20:i386 depends on libgpg-error0 (>= 1.14); however:
  Package libgpg-error0:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgcrypt20:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgcc1:i386
 libc6:i386
 libpcre3:i386
 libgpg-error0:i386
 libselinux1:i386
 liblzma5:i386
 liblz4-1:i386
 libgcrypt20:i386
```

Comment: You could try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` or `sudo apt-get upgrade -f`.

Comment: Same error if I tray any of thouse commands

Comment: What were you doing before this happened? Did you install something or change some repositories? Problems with 32-bit packages...

Comment: @Zanna I tried to instal teamviewer it stock at 33% in the ubuntu software manager then I tray again via console and start getting this error

Comment: I would suggest running `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` but I doubt the packages would have been downloaded if you hadn't. Try it anyway, then see if you can `sudo apt install --reinstall libc6:i386` or remove, and repeat for each package mentioned. If apt will not do anything, you can try removing the packages with dpkg...

Comment: @Zanna No luck on the second command i got:  `sudo apt install --reinstall libc6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2.607 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
E: Internal Error, No file name for libc6:i386`

Answer (score 2):

Solved with `sudo apt install --reinstall gcc-6-base:i386`
thx @zana you give me the idea to solve it.